# How to store chars read from serial port into buffer for processing?

Tags: c, turbo-c++

Right now I have some code that is printing out data read from a serial port with `putch(out)`.  But I need to store it into an array and process it to get floating point values out.

Here is my code just for talking to the serial port, with the calculations omitted:

```
#include <bios.h>
#include <conio.h>

#define COM1       0
#define DATA_READY 0x100

// set the baud rate, parity bit, data width...
#define SETTINGS ( 0xE0 | 0x03 | 0x00 | 0x00)

int main(void)
{
    int in, out, status,i;
    char dataRead[21];
    float roll, pitch;
    bioscom(0, SETTINGS, COM1); /*initialize the port*/
    clrscr();
    cprintf("Data sent to you:  ");    

    while (1) 
    { 
        status = bioscom(3, 0, COM1); // reading the data here
        if (status & DATA_READY)
            if ((out = bioscom(2, 0, COM1) & 0 7F) != 0) 
                putch(out);                // printing read value

        if (kbhit( ))    // If Esc is hit. it breaks and exit.
        { 
            if ((in = getch( )) == ‘ 1B’)   //  1B = Esc
            DONE = TRUE; 
            bioscom(1, in, COM1);  // data write. I am not making use of it.
        } 
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

The incoming data encodes the roll and pitch, as something like `"R:+XXX.XX P:-YYY.YY\r\n"`.

Instead of just printing this data out, I want to store it in the `dataRead[]` array and interpret it into float values.  For instance, `dataRead[2]` to `dataRead[8]` encodes a float value for the "roll" as characters `+XXX.XX`.

How do I store these characters in the array and get the floating point number from it?

If you could write down some code for serial port which does exactly what i want then it would be really helpful. Please make sure it is written in 'C'.

Comment: I am sure neither `‘ 1B’` nor `out = bioscom(2, 0, COM1) & 0 7F` works the way you wrote it here.

Comment: When posting code samples, be sure to remove anything not directly related to your question.  (So for instance `// char TempHold[7]`.)  As @glglgl points out, you probably don't mean `0 7F` but are probably looking for `0x7F` (the 8-bit binary mask 01111111)... and `' 1B'`  shouldn't compile at all (again, you mean `0x1B`?)  Perhaps a simple program that just prints out the data so you can see it and make sure it's what you want would be a better start.  Also, what platform are you on to be using Turbo C++?  Is this a school assignment or can you use something else?

Comment: @HostileFork JFTR, `'\x1B'` and `'\x7F'` should work as well.

Comment: And using `''` instead of `‘’` will be VERY helpful.

Comment: @HostileFork. It's not school assignment. But i am using it because  it has graphics support. Tried same with Dev C++ But did not work. I  believe because of absence of graphics library.

Comment: Turbo C++ is old and discontinued, and I think you will find a much better basis for getting help and support if you use something newer.  If you have to be on Windows and are looking for graphics, there is [SimpleDirectMedia Layer (SDL) for MinGW](https://users.cs.jmu.edu/bernstdh/web/common/help/cpp_mingw-sdl-setup.php).  It can also be beneficial to do your development inside of a virtual machine running Linux such as [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/)--if your computer can run that.  Speaking strictly on the advice of using more current tools...

Comment: I've tried to interpret your question to deduce what you're asking.  See my edit.  Is that correct?  Use the edit button to update it so that it best reflects what you are trying to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Dev C++ but in C++ you have the **strtod** function which converts string to double (float). You need to:

1. collect all characters from the serial port in one text line
2. parse the line

First is easy, just wait until reach "\n". Something like:

```
 char line [MAX_LINE];
 if(out == '\n')
   parse_line(line. ....)
 else
   line[n_readed++] = out;
```

The second part is more tricky. You can use some text processing library for parsing or write your
own parse function using **strtod**. Since your case is simple I would rather do the second. Here is an example of the parse function which reads your text lines:

```
 const char* line = "R:+123.56P:-767.77\r\n";

 // return true on success
 bool parse_line(const char* line, double* R, double* P)
 {
    const char* p = line;

    if(*p++ != 'R')
      return false;

    if(*p++ != ':')
      return false;

    if(*p == '+') // + sign is optional
      p++ ;

    char* pEnd;
    *R = strtod (p, &pEnd);

    if(pEnd == p)
      return false;

    p = pEnd;

    if(*p++ != 'P')
      return false;

    if(*p++ != ':')
      return false;

    *P = strtod (p, &pEnd);

    if(pEnd == p)
      return false;

    return true;
}

int main()
{
  double R,P;
  if(!parse_line(line, &R, &P))
     printf("error\n");
  else
     printf("sucessfully readed: %f\t%f\n", R,P);

  return 0;
}
```

You need to declare two float arrays and to fill them with the parsed float values when the parsing function returns true. Otherwise there have been some error, probably because of damaged data. Also you can change all doubles with floats.

I hope this to help you.